# Accumulation Points Questions.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im studying accumulation points and the theory seems quiet simply however the questions i cant seem to figure out.

$$(1+1/n)^n$$ I know the limit of this as $n\rightarrow\infty= e$, however 
is this the only accumulation point?

Also $$1/n+cos(n\pi)$$ I know '$cos(n\pi)$' on its own has accumulation points $1,0,-1$ do these get affected by the $1/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the graph of $(1+1/n)^n$: (From Wolfram Alpha)

http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP10872190dee7fd9hib5900000ee9b8fc3aa41iaa?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=7&w=320.&h=124.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

The limit as $n\to\infty$ is simply $e$, and there is no other accumulation point.

The graph of $1/n+\cos(n\pi)$: From Wolfram Alpha:

http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP33191hi6h783e2d37c1700004afb9g0afg9ed43b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6&w=298.&h=124.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

The function is periodic, and hence, does not have a single accumulation point. Instead, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n+\cos(n\pi))=-1\text{ to }1$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to know how to get these results when you don't have Wolfram Alpha available. Namely, $(1+1/n)^n$ has no other accumulation point because the limit exists and hence every convergent sub-sequence must converge to the same limit. Also, the partition odd-even of $\mathbb{N}$ not only shows that $1/n+\cos(n \pi)$ has at least the two accumulation points $-1$ and $1$, but it also shows it has no other, since every sub-sequence of the sequence $a_n := n$ must have an infinity of even terms or an infinity of odd terms.

Comment: @Amateur I will make my answer community wiki, so that if you wish, you may add your above comment in the answer.

Comment: thank you, just one question, why would $1/n+cos(n\pi)$ not also have $0$ as an accumulation point?

Comment: @help It does. It takes on values $-1\text{ to }1$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a convergent sequence of real numbers cannot have more than one accumulation point. Suppose that $a_n\to L$ and it has an accumulation point $M\ne L$. Then, because infinitely many points $a_i$ are within any given distance $\epsilon$ of $M$, there is no $N$ such that after $n>N$ we will always have $$|a_n-L|<\frac{|M-L|}{2}$$ taking $$\epsilon=\frac{|M-L|}{2}$$ because then we would get $$|a_n-M|<\frac{|M-L|}{2}$$ for some $n>N$ and hence $$|M-L|=|M-a_n+a_n-L|\le|a_n-M|+|a_n-L|< |M-L|$$ a contradiction on good days. Therefore $M=N$ and the limit is the only accumulation point.

The second function (assuming you are working with integers) goes between $-1$ and $1$. Because $1/n$ gets arbitrarily small, those two numbers will be the accumulation points of the function.